# Localizations of an integral domain with respect to finite prime ideals

Tags: commutative-algebra

I think the following proposition is likely to be true. 
I'd like to know a proof of it if any.

**Proposition**
Let $A$ be an integral domain, $K$ its field of fractions.
Let $P_1, ..., P_n$ be prime ideals of $A$.
Let $S = (A - P_1)\cap\cdots\cap(A - P_n)$.
If we regard $A_S$ and $A_{P_1}, \ldots, A_{P_n}$ as subrings of K,
then $A_S = A_{P_1}\cap \cdots\cap A_{P_n}$.

**EDIT**
I came up with a proof thanks to the Bill's hint.
Let $\alpha \in A_{P_1}\cap \cdots\cap A_{P_n}$.
Let $I$ = {$x \in A; x\alpha \in A$}.
$I$ is an ideal of $A$.
Since $I$ is not contained in any $P_i$, it is not contained in $P_1\cup\cdots\cup P_n$ by Proposition 1.11 of Atiyah-MacDonald.
Hence $\alpha \in A_S$.
Therefore $A_{P_1}\cap \cdots\cap A_{P_n} ⊂ A_S$.
The other inculsion is obvious.

Comment: Certainly, one direction is clear: if $x\in A_S$, so that $x=\frac{a}{s}$ for some $a\in A$ and $s\in S=(A-P_1)\cap \cdots\cap (A-P_n)$, then certainly $s\in A-P_i$ for all $i$, so that $x\in A_{P_i}$ for all $i$, so that $x\in A_{P_1}\cap\cdots\cap A_{P_n}$. Thus $A_S\subseteq A_{P_1}\cap\cdots\cap A_{P_n}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $ An integral domain $\displaystyle \rm\:D = \bigcap_{max\ M}\! D_{\:\!M}.\ $  Now put $\rm\:D = A_S.\:$

**Proof** $\ $ If fraction $\rm\:f\not\in D\:$ then its denominator ideal $\rm\: I = \{ d\mid  d\:\!f\in D\} \ne (1),\:$ so $\rm\!\: I\!\:$ is contained in a maximal ideal $\rm\:M,\:$ so $\rm\:f\not\in D_M,\:$ thus $\rm\:f\:$ is not in the intersection. The converse is clear. $ \ $ **QED**

Comment: Thanks. I think we need the following result to apply your hint.

*Let $I$ be an ideal of A. If $I ⊂ P_1\cup\cdots\cup P_n$, then $I ⊂ P_i$ for some $i$.*

The proof can be found in Atiyah-MacDonald, Proposition 1.11.

Comment: @Makoto Kato I dont think we need that. Your result directly follows from Bill's hint. But I am curious and cant see why $I$ is not contained in any $P_i$ in your solution above.